# When I place text into a div and then subsequently move that text around, how do I make the div expand/contract due to the moved text?

Tags: html, css

When I move the text down in this example, the div does not move to encompass the text, how can I make the div react to the move in text?

```css
.background {background: black}
.margin {position:relative;
    top:60px;
color:green}
```

```html
<html>
<link rel=stylesheet href=main.css type=text/css>
  <div class=background >
    
    
  
     
   
    <a   class=margin >me
    </a
   </div>
 
   
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand what you're asking here.

Do you mean that you want the div to contain the text?

If so then remove the relative positioning.

Or if you want to add space above the text and have the div enlarge with each line of text then use line breaks 
 as so:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel=stylesheet href=main.css type=text/css>
<style>
  .background{
    background: black;
  }

  .margin{
    color:green;
  }


</style>
</head>
  <div class=background>
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
        <a class=margin> me </a>
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want the div to enlarge with each lien that gets added to the div then take off the positioning and add line breaks to the div such as: <br/>

Comment: But what if I didn't want the standard line break had randomlly shaped contact going into the div tags?  There's no way to make the tag adjust automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the height on the div first and then position the anchor tag absolutely with respect to the bottom of the div.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Voreny/1ghvh38j/):

```
<div class="background">
  <a class="margin">me</a>
</div>

.background {
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
}
.margin {
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  color:green
}
```

I also refactored the code, because it looked not too well.

Comment: So it's not possible for a div to expand/contract based on the CSS of a nested element?  What if I had a while loop operating which input pictures of various heights?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure of what you're asking, but here are two ways to do it based on my interpretation of your question.

Move the Div along with the A element:

```
.background {
  background: black;
}
.margin {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 60px;
  color:green
}

<div class=background >
    <a class="margin">me</a>
</div>
```

Make the Div expand to the movement of the A tag:

```
.background {
  background: black;
}
.padding {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 60px;
  color:green
}

<div class=background >
    <a class="padding">me</a>
</div>
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/0ns1g1ca/